# Probability Distribution Doubt

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

1) A drawer full of AAA batteries contains 40 batteries, but 6 of them are dead. Suppose 4 batteries are randomly selected from the drawer to use.

a) What is the probability that all four are good? 
(I used the Hypergeometric Distribution equation $ P(x) ={ \binom{k}{x} \binom{N - k}{n - x } \over \binom{N}{n}}$  assuming that the variables are N=40, k=34, n=4, x=4 )

$ P(x=4) ={ \binom{34}{4} \binom{40 - 34}{4 - 4 } \over \binom{40}{4}}$

$ P(x=4) = 0.507 $

would this be the correct way to answer this question?

b) What is the probability that exactly one dead battery is selected amount the 4? 
(I assume the hypergeometric applies to this as well. Using $N=40$, $k=6$, $n=4$,$x=1$)

$ P(x=1) ={ \binom{6}{1} \binom{40 - 4}{4 - 1 } \over \binom{40}{4}}$

I don't think this is right. I am confused how to set this equation right.

I want to know what the variables for this equation stand for. I am confused on what each mean. So far from what i understand is N = total # of things, n = randomly select without replacement, x = # of successes we need)

Comment: For the second one, you should pick 3 out of 34, not 36

Comment: A nice little mnemonic: the top numbers in the binomial coefficients in the numerator add to the top number in the binomial coefficient in the denominator. The same is true for the bottom numbers. Thus your "40-4" should be 40-6. This mnemonic is not at all arbitrary, it has combinatoric content to it.

Comment: Specifically, the top numbers are the two subgroups that you are choosing from, which must add up to the size of the whole population; the bottom numbers are the numbers that you're choosing from each subgroup, which must add up to the total number of things that you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first answer is correct.

One other easy way to do this.

1. Probability = $\frac{C(34,4)}{C(40,4)}$
2. Probability = $\frac{C(34,3) * C(6,1)}{C(40,4)}$